# intellij idea gradle generated sources not recognized on custom idea plugin

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to create my custom plugin for idea.

The thing is, when I'm building the project there is error `package 'name' does not exist` reffering to generated source, but everything compiles without errors. Obviously, generated source folder is marked as generated.

My project structure is like this:

```
project_name
 src
   main
       gen (generated source)
       java
```

**What did I tried:**

- Invalidate Caches/Restart,
- Mark src folder as source and remove source mark from everywhere else,
- Delete .idea folder and rebuild

My intellij version is 2019.3.3

**Update**

I tried to add to build.gradle this, but nothing changed:

`idea.module.sourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated-source/")`

Comment: Can you build by Gradle from command line?

Comment: `idea.module.sourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated-source/")` this will mark the `/build/generated-source/` directory as generated source, but you have it in `src/main/gen` directory.

Comment: Provide a sample project if issue remains.

Comment: @Andrey , I tried to build with ```src/main/generated-source``` actually, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Andrey Also I notised that if i'll build project without some generated classes - my normal classes and packages appear's in ```build``` folder, but in ```generated``` there is no any class. Here's the link to see successful build w/o generated resources. 
[link](https://imgur.com/TrME9cA)